# Exposing .NET Web API Ports on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web Service API console application in VS, for .NET 6, and specified the ports 6060 and 6061, where I want them to listen:

app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:6060");
app.Urls.Add("https://localhost:6061");

Deployed the application on Linux (Amazon Linux 2).

Then, went to the AWS management console added Outbound rules to open ports 6060 and 6061.

I can connect to ports 6060 and 6061 locally using Telnet, from the same Linux machine, but the ports 6060 and 6061 are still unaccessible from outside.

And, it is not a lag with exposing ports on AWS, because if I run another service on those ports, I CAN connect to them.  They are open.

Must be missing something simple and obvious.  Did anyone else experience the same problem?

Thanks
Archie

Comment: change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  The suggestion from Lei Yang to change the localhost to 0.0.0. worked!  Thank you very much!